# Call of Duty: Modern Warfare Remastered can't download

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

There was a limited offer for buying the game **Modern Warfare Remastered** inside the main menu of *Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare*.

I clicked it to go to the store and purchased the game, but there's no way to download it. It says `Cannot find the application. Do you want to look in Playstation Store?`

How can I download the game?

Comment: Have you contacted Playstation and/or the Call of Duty company? Check to make the purchase was complete by checking your credit/debit card's transactions.

Comment: I was trying but the chat are offline for both sides. I did purchase Call of duty: Infinite Warfare on Amazon and from the store the other one, of course.

Comment: I suggest calling not online live chat. They're legit never there ;) . I tried to sort out my account getting hacked but PS4 was just like NOPE NOT HAPPENING!

Comment: Haha @ExperimentalRocket The thing is right now I'm in Venezuela and not sure how to call support from here.

Comment: May the reason that you cant download be due to your location? They have different versions of the game for each language i tink

Comment: Uhm, don't think so. Since I'm using and American account (my PSN) Also, they wouln't allow me to buy it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you guys have this problem. I contact Sony and they help me out, you need to download the game from your account via PC.